How to Prevent Telegram Inline Keyboard Buttons from Collapsing in Aiogram 3
I'm developing a Telegram bot using Aiogram 3, and I'm facing an issue with inline keyboards. When the photo is narrow, the inline keyboard buttons collapse into three dots. I want to ensure that the caption of the photo is extended to a fixed size to prevent this behavior without changing the visible caption text.
I have tried various approaches, such as using different hidden symbols and padding with spaces, but none have worked except for changing the text to make it bigger, but this doesn`t suits me.
Here is the code I have tried:
# Using Zero Width Space (U+200B)
padding = "\u200B" * 50  # Adjust the number to meet your needs
await message.answer_photo(
    caption=f"Short message{padding}",
    photo=config.registration_photo_file_id,
    reply_markup=edit_date_buttons,
    parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
)

await message.answer_photo(
    caption=f"Short message{padding}",
    photo=config.registration_photo_file_id,
    reply_markup=edit_date_buttons,
    parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2
)

await message.answer_photo(
    caption=f"Short message{padding}",
    photo=config.registration_photo_file_id,
    reply_markup=edit_date_buttons,
    parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN
)

# Using Spaces
padding = " " * 50  # Adjust the number to meet your needs
await message.answer_photo(
    caption=f"Short message{padding}",
    photo=config.registration_photo_file_id,
    reply_markup=edit_date_buttons
)

await message.answer_photo(
    caption=f"Short message",
    photo=config.registration_photo_file_id,
    reply_markup=edit_date_buttons
)

# Using Newline Characters
padding = "\n" * 55
await message.answer_photo(
    caption=f"Short{padding}",
    photo=config.registration_photo_file_id,
    reply_markup=edit_date_buttons
)

# Using HTML with Zero Width Non-Joiner (&#x200D;)
padding = " " * 55
await message.answer_photo(
    caption=f"<pre>myMessage                                                 &#x200D;</pre>",
    photo=config.registration_photo_file_id,
    reply_markup=edit_date_buttons,
    parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML
)

Despite these attempts, the hidden symbols are stripped and only sending a large visible text works. How can I ensure that my message's caption extends to a fixed size without altering the visible text?
